# Mac osx terminal commands in an automation

Tags: string, macos, shell, variables, automation

I need to create an automation that takes files as inputs and uses their location string as an input variable to a script. I also need it ask for a string before running the script. How would I go about doing this?

The command line code I want to execute:

```
convert (file-location) -page '(string)' (file-location)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I figured out that you'd use "Run Applescript" and I eventually got it to work.

Comment: :: if your question is solved, you should post the answer you finally used below, and mark that as the correct answer to the question and therefore mark it as solved and closed.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
#!/bin/bash 
if [ $# -ne 2 ]
then
    echo "Usage: $0 <path_to_input_file>"
fi

echo "Processing $1. Enter string: "
read a

convert $1 -page "$a" $1
```

You invoke this script with one file name at a time, for that file it asks you for the string to be used. You could rewrite this to loop over a bunch of files too.